# How could I use IProtectFocus to keep CDHtmlDialog navigate from drawing focus from editBox?

Tags: c++, com, focus, activex

I know IProtectFocus interface AllowFocusChange function could solve the "focus steal issue" when CDHtmlDialog excute the navigate() functions, but I don't quite clear about how to implement IProtectFocus function into my code. Could anyone please help me out? Any code sample is quite appreciate.

More details, I could implement IInternetSecurityManager interface to fix javascript ActiveX authority issue. But I tried the same way to implement IProtectFocus, do not work.
I need C++ code only, thanks!

My code example:(CCustomControlSite is customized IWebBrowser control, CInstantAnswerDlg is a CDHtmlDialog.)

MFC interface part:

```
class CCustomControlSite: public COleControlSite    
{

public:
CCustomControlSite(COleControlContainer *pCnt):COleControlSite(pCnt){}

protected:
DECLARE_INTERFACE_MAP();
    // Implement IServiceProvider
    BEGIN_INTERFACE_PART(ServiceProvider, IServiceProvider)
        STDMETHOD(QueryService)(REFGUID,REFIID,void**);
    END_INTERFACE_PART(ServiceProvider)

    // Implement IServiceProvider
    BEGIN_INTERFACE_PART(ProtectFocus, IProtectFocus)
        STDMETHOD(AllowFocusChange)(BOOL *);
    END_INTERFACE_PART(ProtectFocus)
};
```

Implementation part:

```
ULONG FAR EXPORT CCustomControlSite::XServiceProvider::AddRef()
{
    METHOD_PROLOGUE(CCustomControlSite, ServiceProvider)
        return pThis->ExternalAddRef();
}

 ULONG FAR EXPORT CCustomControlSite::XServiceProvider::Release()
 {                            
    METHOD_PROLOGUE(CCustomControlSite, ServiceProvider)
    return pThis->ExternalRelease();
 }

HRESULT FAR EXPORT CCustomControlSite::XServiceProvider::QueryInterface(REFIID riid,void** ppvObj)
 {
    METHOD_PROLOGUE(CCustomControlSite, ServiceProvider)
    HRESULT hr = (HRESULT)pThis->ExternalQueryInterface(&riid, ppvObj);
    return hr;
 }

STDMETHODIMP CCustomControlSite::XServiceProvider::QueryService(REFGUID guidService,REFIID riid,void** ppvObject)
{
    if (guidService == SID_SInternetSecurityManager && 
    riid == IID_IInternetSecurityManager)
    {
        METHOD_PROLOGUE(CCustomControlSite, ServiceProvider)
        HRESULT hr = (HRESULT)pThis->ExternalQueryInterface(&riid, ppvObject);
    return hr;
} 
else 
{
    *ppvObject = NULL;
}
return E_NOINTERFACE;
}

// ProtectFocus Methods
ULONG FAR EXPORT CCustomControlSite::XProtectFocus::AddRef()
{
    METHOD_PROLOGUE(CCustomControlSite, ProtectFocus)
        return pThis->ExternalAddRef();
 }

ULONG FAR EXPORT CCustomControlSite::XProtectFocus::Release()
{                            
    METHOD_PROLOGUE(CCustomControlSite, ProtectFocus)
        return pThis->ExternalRelease();
}

 HRESULT FAR EXPORT CCustomControlSite::XProtectFocus::QueryInterface(REFIID riid,void** ppvObj)
{
    METHOD_PROLOGUE(CCustomControlSite, ProtectFocus)
        HRESULT hr = (HRESULT)pThis->ExternalQueryInterface(&riid, ppvObj);
     return hr;
}

 STDMETHODIMP CCustomControlSite::XProtectFocus::AllowFocusChange(BOOL *pfAllow)
 {
     *pfAllow = FALSE;
      return S_OK;
 }
```

Add control to CDHtmlDialog:

```
BOOL CInstantAnswerDlg::CreateControlSite(COleControlContainer* pContainer,COleControlSite** ppSite,UINT /* nID */,REFCLSID /* clsid */ )
{
    if(ppSite == NULL)
    {
        ASSERT(FALSE);
        return FALSE;
    }
    m_pCustSite = m_insAnswerManager->CreateSite(pContainer);
    if (!m_pCustSite)
        return FALSE;
    *ppSite = m_pCustSite;
    return TRUE;    
}
```

The question is both XProtectFocus::QueryInterface and XProtectFocus::AllowFocusChange function do not get called, while XServiceProvider::QueryInterface could get called. where am I wrong??

Comment: Please add language tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The place you put implementation of IProtectFocus and IInternetSecurityManager depends on your  implementation of QueryService. Since you are calling CCustomControlSite::ExternalQueryInterface in your implementation, you need to add [interface map macros](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5hhehwba.aspx) on the CCustomControlSite class.

Comment: Thanks sheng, I have read the MSDN Document, and added ProtectFocus interface to my CCustomControlSite class, but when the code excute, it do not call my function. I have edited my question, please help me check the issue, many thanks.